# Grep failing with Emacs (windows), and GnuWin32 Grep

Tags: emacs, grep, search

I've downloaded and installed the GnuWin32 tools, and added the grep executables to the Emacs bin. I've also, for what its worth, added the GnuWin32 bin folder to my Path variable.

Problem is though, when I try and run with suggested grep commands, I always get:

```
Grep exited abnormally with code 53 at Wed Feb 24 17:16:12
```

For the life of me, I can't find any reference to error code 53 anywhere! :(

I've tried the exact examples on a number of websites for example, when I enter:

```
M-x grep <ret>
```

It comes up with

```
Run grep (like this): grep -n
```

Which is fine, but I have no idea of what parameters it expects. I've tried some in some tuorials, but I get error code 53 again!

One of the things I've tried is straight from the emacs wiki (http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/GrepMode#toc2) (maybe not for the windows version though?) and it says to try this command:

```
M-x grep -n -e setq ~/.emacs
```

Which I've tried and I get:

```
-*- mode: grep; default-directory: "c:/[My Directory]/" -*-
Grep started at Wed Feb 24 17:30:47

grep -n -e setq ~/.emacs NUL

Grep exited abnormally with code 53 at Wed Feb 24 17:30:47
```

So frustrating as this is meant to be a powerful feature of Emacs and I'm really trying to learn it as I've heard good things about it!

Any help would be appreciated! :)

Andy

**UPDATE**

From the suggestion below, I've tried it via command line and it seems to work fine, perhaps there some config I'm missing?

**UPDATE**

I've found the command M-x Occur which seems to do much the same as I would image grep does. Are there many extra benefits to using grep over occur if I can't get this working?

Comment: Response to second update: `M-x occur` generally only searches within a single open buffer whereas `M-x grep` searches through multiple files - very useful.

Comment: You might want to try `M-x multi-occur` if grep doesn't work.  It searches through the open buffers.  Not quite the same thing as grep, but at least it is something.

Comment: Thanks, that may come in useful! :) Still haven't got it working, but have no more time left for playing around with it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Download the [dependencies zip file](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm) and copy `libiconv2.dll`, `libintl3.dll`, `pcre3.dll` and `regex2.dll` to Emacs' `bin` directory.

> Copy `grep.exe` and `find.exe` to Emacs' own `bin` directory. Emacs will then use these files over any other executables with the same name, including Windows' own `find` utility.
>
> **Note:** if you don't use the installer, you need to download the [dependencies zip file](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm) as well and copy `libiconv2.dll`, `libintl3.dll`, `pcre3.dll` and `regex2.dll` to Emacs' `bin` directory, otherwise you may get an "exited abnormally with code 53" error message.

[EmacsWiki: Grep Mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/GrepMode)

Answer (score 1):

The exit code of 53 is possibly an OS exit code rather than a grep-specific exit code. For windows this would be "The network path was not found". Are you doing anything over a network path? Are there any missing dll's that grep needs? Can you successfully run grep on the command line?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestions!

I'm not doing anything over the network, so I'm not sure that'd be the problem. Just fired up cmd and it seems to work fine (at least no error code 53). I'm still not sure of the command syntax but I tried grep -n [regex] [file] and it seems to return search results. So why not with Emacs! Grrrr!!! :)

Comment: Can you check what version of emacs and grep (`grep --version` from command line) you are using.

Comment: I'm using GNU grep 2.5.4 and emacs 23.1. I'm assumming they're the later (if not latest) versions as I only just downloaded it all a week or so ago. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, more information about emacs: GNU Emacs 23.1.1 (i386-mingw-nt5.1.2600)

Comment: Possibly it's a path problem. In your *scratch* buffer do a (getenv "PATH") and execute it with C-j. Is grep in that path?

Comment: Yep, I've got the folder containing grep in the path (C:\GnuWin32\bin). I also read somewhere to copy the executables to the Emacs bin directory, which I've done. I think its so the GNU versions of commands like Find are used over the windows ones. Hmmm...

Comment: I wouldn't copy the executables to the emacs dir.  Just put the dir on the system path, and make sure that when emacs starts, it uses that system path.

Comment: the exit code 53 is meaning some dll file is missing.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and the following worked for me.

1. Go to the windows console
2. Enter the command "set" to bring up your system variables
3. I had shell=c:\progra~1\rational\ration~1\nutcroot\mksnt\sh.exe
4. Enter "set shell=" to remove the variable
5. Try Emacs again

Good luck!

Comment: Hey,

Thanks for the tip, but I gave up on Emacs ages ago, the learning curve was just too steep for what I was going to get out of it and I ended up using Notepad++ instead! :)

..So unfortunately I can't test it!

Andy